# Constraining the length of a list type in an XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have created an XML schema for an abstract set element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.dummy.com/xml/sets/"
    targetNamespace="http://www.dummy.com/xml/sets/">
    <xs:group name="SetElement">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Label" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

Importing this schema, I am trying to create an XML schema for a finite set object that has a cardinality element storing the cardinality of the set, and a list of elements of `listType="SetElement"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.dummy.com/xml/sets/"
    xmlns="http://www.dummy.com/xml/sets/">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.dummy.com/xml/sets/"
        schemaLocation="setelement.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Cardinality" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="SetElements">
        <xs:list itemType="SetElement"><xs:length value=""></xs:length></xs:list>
    </xs:simpleType>    
</xs:schema>
```

Since the set must contain exactly the number of elements specified by the `Cardinality` element, is there anyway of using that to constrain the length facet of the `SetElements` list type?

Does anyone have any suggestions for solving this general problem?  If have a schema for any finite collection or list or set object which knows its cardinality, is there any way of using that to specify the list of its elements of a size exactly up to its cardinality?

Thanks for any suggestions. SRM.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in XSD 1.1 with assertions. Something like this:

```
<xs:assert test="Cardinality = count(data(SetElements))"/>
```

XSD 1.1 is supported in recent releases of Saxon and Xerces.

If you aren't able to use XSD 1.1, consider adding a Schematron validation phase.

Michael Kay
Saxonica